# Tkinter Entry validatation

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am writing a program in Python 3.6 using Tkinter where a customer has multiple(11) entry fields. I want these entry fields to only accept integers and also be able to define the maximum amount of characters.

I already have a function that does this. But this function only works for one entry field. I have tried entering variables with calling the function so it changes another entry field for example. I was not able to do this.

This is the function I have that works with 1 entry field.

```
    def limitMuntgeld(self, *args):
        value = self.invoerM.get()
        if len(value) > 5:
            self.invoerM.set(value[:5])
        if value.lower() in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-=[];/":
            self.invoerM.set(value[:0])
```

This is the example entry field code that works with the function

```
self.invoerMuntgeld = Entry(self, font=('Arial', 14), textvariable=self.invoerM)
```

This is combined with a trace on the entry field posted below.

```
self.invoerM = StringVar()
self.invoerM.trace('w', self.limitMuntgeld)
```

I have also tried it with vcmd and validatecommand. However, no good results.
My endresult would be one function working with all entry fields. If anyone has any suggestions, I am all ears!

Comment: using `validatecommand` is the proper way to do this type of validation. Perhaps you can show what you tried.

Comment: please provide a testable example. Try to follow the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). guidelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to do entry validation is with the `validatecommand` option rather than using `trace`. With the validation feature built into the widget you don't need a reference to the widget itself (though you can use it if you want).

When the `validatecommand` is run, you can have it pass in what the new value will be if the input is valid. You only need to check this value and then return `True` or `False`, without having to know which widget it applies to.

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def validate_input(new_value):
    valid = new_value .isdigit() and len(new_value) <= 5
    return valid

root = tk.Tk()

validate = root.register(validate_input)
for i in range(10):
    entry = tk.Entry(root, validate="key", validatecommand=(validate, "%P"))
    entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")

root.mainloop()
```

For information about what `%P` represents, and what else can be used as arguments to the command, see this question: [Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4140437/7432)

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that I was using the function in a poor way and had a bad result. It is also due to the fact that I just started using classes and might not be too efficient in that way of working.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I don't fully understand how the validatecommand works. I understand that "%P" is given with the function. How does this continue?

I have a small error in my code now. The entry box only allows integers. But when I "backspace"" the integers, the first integer will not be removed.

Comment: @Cris1660: It's pretty simple: if the function returns `True`, the modification is allowed. The first integer will not be removed because the code doesn't allow the empty string. Just add a case that returns `True` if the new value is blank.